# Deploying Server 2012 with DNS role using WDS and answer file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, powershell, wds

I want to deploy an image using WDS on Server 2012. I will be using an answer file for unattended installation with little touch as possible. My answer file works great but I can't get the auto-logon to work and the FirstLogonCommand to run. I added `Components\7 oobeSystem\amd64_ Microsoft-Windows- Shell-Setup _neutral\FirstLogonCommands` to my answer file using Windows Image Manager and added these values:

```
CommandLine = powershell -command Install-WindowsFeature DNS –IncludeManagementTools -IncludeAllSubFeature -Restart
Description =Install dns server
Order = 1
```

Then I did auto logon located at `Components\7 oobeSystem\amd64_ Microsoft-Windows- Shell-Setup _neutral\Autologon` and added these values:

```
Domain = contoso
Enabled = true
LogonCount = 1
Typed the password
Username = Administrator
```

These two components alone don't work. It installs Server 2012 OK and bypasses all the screens I want to bypass, and it even joins the domain contoso successfully.

I have to manually logon and then when I logon no scripts or anything is run. When server manager opens DNS role is not installed and not even located under tools.

Things I tried:

Open cmd as admin and typed: `powershell -command Install-WindowsFeature DNS –IncludeManagementTools -IncludeAllSubFeature -Restart` this worked and installed roles successfully

If I missed anything to help you troubleshoot just ask.

Comment: When I make scheduled tasks with powershelll I use "powershell.exe -noninteractive <rest of args>" Your case is slightly similar, maybe the same would help.